# Is theBattlefield 3 skin for Mass Effect 3 only available on same system?

Tags: mass-effect-3, battlefield-3, origin

I have *Battlefield 3* for PC and *Mass Effect 3* for Xbox 360. I'm signed with the same account on Origin, but I can't get the *Battlefield 3* multiplayer skin for *Mass Effect 3* (though I have the N7 dogtag for *Battlefield 3*). Is this as it is supposed to be, or do I have to do something else to receive the reward?

Comment: Is there a special box in the Store in multipalyer for you to buy (for free)? I think that's how the DLC was awarded for other stuff

Comment: nothing in the origin client on my pc, nothing in the "extra" section of mass effect, nothing on the xbox marketplace

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo Not in the extras section - on the Mass Effect 3 main menu, click on "Multiplayer" and then "Store" in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, both online passes [must](http://social.bioware.com/forums/forum/1/topic/345/index/10848517/1#10909484) be redeemed on the same platform.**

That would be PC+PC or 360+360, as [the skin isn't available for PS3](https://help.ea.com/article/battlefield-3-multiplayer-skin-not-available-for-ps3-me3-purchasers).